# How make client side load balancing with grpc in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, grpc, grpc-dart

How implement client side load balancing in flutter with the package https://pub.dev/packages/grpc

Comment: you should check official documentation on this [https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.